# How to have my picture on the left and text on the right ( Bootstrap )

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

```css
body{
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 1rem ;
}
.navbar-brand{
    font-family: 'Syne Mono', monospace;
    color: black;
    size: 0.5rem;
}
header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: rgb(237,104,104);
background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(237,104,104,1) 0%, rgba(232,118,118,1) 50%, rgba(236,159,159,1) 100%);
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 2;
}
.navbar-color{
    background: rgb(237,104,104);
background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(237,104,104,1) 0%, rgba(232,118,118,1) 50%, rgba(236,159,159,1) 100%);
}
.nav-link{
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<!--Navbar-->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-color bg-light fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav"
                aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarNav">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true"></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </nav>
        <!--Header-->
    <header>
        <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="col-md-6"><img src="/images/Online shopping _Outline.svg" alt="shoppingicon">
    <div class="col-md-6">Textrheoefjfoj
    </div>
    </div>
    </header>

</body>
</html>
```

**Hello! I'm still new to web development. Someone suggested that I use bootstrap so it would make it easier for me to learn web development. I don't know how grids 100% work, so I want to know how I can have my picture on the left and my text next to it. [image: Basically an example of what I want, picture on the right and text on the left.]**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap your `div's` into `row` class:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <img src="/images/Online shopping _Outline.svg" alt="shoppingicon">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            Textrheoefjfoj
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Like this [from Boostrap grid system here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/)

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      The First column
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      The Second column
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That really helped, thank you a lot! The thing is the text isnt 100% showing on my first column, `<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <h1>The First cohhhhhhhhhhhhh</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <img src="/images/Online shopping _Outline.svg" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>`

Comment: @naboulsi  I am glad that it helped to you! [Try to use overflow-wrap property to break words](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/overflow-wrap/)

Comment: @SaveUp Same thing, didn't do anything. I tried inherit and breakword. The text has to be long so a part of it will show.

Comment: @naboulsi  could you reproduce such behavior at [codepen](https://codepen.io/sqphy/pen/LJxpXx)

Comment: @SaveUp Here you go [https://codepen.io/hnaboulsi/pen/WNRbLLp]

Comment: @naboulsi there is 404 error. In addition, you can ask a new question with work link to codepen as we found how to create two columns side by side.